# Existence of fundamental class of $H_i(M,\partial M;R)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Here $M$ is a compact connected manifold with boundary, how to show there is relative a fundamental class of $H_i(M,\partial M;R)$?

Here fundamental class means an element of $H_n(M,\partial M;R)$ whose image in $H_n(M|x;R)$ is a generator for all $x\in M−\partial M$

Comment: what definition of fundamental class are you using?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez   An element of $H_n(M; R)$ whose image in $H_n(M |x; R)$ is a generator for all $x\in M-\partial M$

Comment: That cannot be the definition you are using, because that is a property of an element in the abolute cohomology group, whiile your question is about a relative one... In any case, once you decide what definition you are working with, add it to the question itself.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you, but this is from Hatcher's book https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch3.pdf p.253,  the second paragraph from the bottom, can you take a look?

Comment: I can't right now. But your questionclearly asks for an element of $H_i(M,\partial M)$ while the definition you quoted refers to an element of $H_i(M)$. Clearly, that cannot be the definition of what you want.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sorry, I made a typo, I mean an element of $H_i(M,\partial M;R)$, and I have added the right definition.

Comment: I think you need an additional hypothesis. What about the special case $\partial M=\emptyset$, or if you insist on a non empty boundary, look at the Mobius strip.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus $R$-orientability of $M$ is a sufficient extra hypothesis.

Comment: @KyleMiller Yes thats what I had in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that if the boundary has a collar neighborhood, then the inclusion $(M,\partial M\times[0,\varepsilon))\to (M,\partial M)$ is a homotopy equivalence.  Followed by excision, then $H_n(M,\partial M;R)$ is isomorphic to $H_n(M-\partial M,\partial M\times(0,\varepsilon);R)$.  Now, **if** $M$ is $R$-orientable, then so is the open submanifold $M-\partial M$, and Lemma 3.27 applies since $(M-\partial M)-(\partial M\times (0,\varepsilon))$ is a compact subset.  The lemma implies that this homology group has a unique generator which is a relative fundamental class.  The fact that it actually is a relative fundamental class of $(M,\partial M)$ is due to naturality.

In particular, let $x\in M-\partial M$ (Hatcher's definition of a manifold with boundary being orientable is only for interior points).  There is some $\varepsilon$ such that $x$ is not in $\partial M\times (0,2\varepsilon)$, so $H_n(M,M-x;R)$ is naturally isomorphic to $H_n(M-\partial M,\partial M\times (0,\varepsilon);R)$, and it must be the local orientation at $x$ since $H_n(M,M-x;R)$ is naturally isomorphic to $H_n(U,U-x;R)$ for some open $U\subset M-\partial M\times(0,\varepsilon)$.

Edit: I've made a mess of further explanation by avoiding typing a commutative diagram, so I've at least drawn one.  The lemma gives a class $\alpha$ whose image in $H_n(M,\partial M)$ is something that, when restricted to a small enough neighborhood $U$, gives a local orientation.

[image: Commutative diagram]

Comment: Thank you, I know we can apply the lemma to get a fundamental class for $H_n(M-\partial M,\partial M\times(0,\varepsilon);R)$, but I can't see how to apply naturally to show the existence of fundamental class of $H_n(M,\partial M; R)$. Can you explain more about the naturally?

Comment: Why is $H_n(M,M-x;R)$ is naturally isomorphic to $H_n(M-\partial M,\partial M\times (0,\varepsilon);R)$?

Comment: $H_n(M,M-x;R)$ is naturally $H_n(M-\partial M,M-\partial M - x;R)$ by excision, and the inclusion map $(M-\partial M,M-\partial M-x)\to (M-\partial M, \partial M\times(0,\varepsilon))$ induces an isomorphism on $H_n$.

Comment: (M−∂M,M−∂M−x)→(M−∂M,∂M×(0,ε)) is not an inclusion.

Comment: Ok, the inclusion $(M-\partial M,\partial M\times (0,\varepsilon)-x)\to(M-\partial M,M-\partial M-x)$ induces an isomorphism, and the first is isomorphic to $H_n(M-\partial M,\partial M\times(0,\varepsilon))$ due to the lemma.

Comment: Sorry, why does the inclusion induce an isomorphism? Not every inclusion induces isomorphism, doesn't it?

Comment: @6666 I was trying to patch in extra supporting reasoning, but that wasn't going well.  The commutative diagram, which I was avoiding typing out earlier, should be good.  Commutativity of the upper left square could be explained by homotopy equivalence of the long exact sequences associated to the inclusion of triples $(M,M-x,\partial M)\to(M,M-x,\partial M\times[0,\varepsilon))$.

Comment: Wait, but why is $(M,\partial M)\to(M,\partial M\times[0,\varepsilon))$ a homotopy equivalence?

Comment: @Zhuo One argument is to show instead that $(M,\partial M)\to(M,\partial M\times[0,\varepsilon/2))$ is a homotopy equivalence, where for the map in the reverse direction you use the map $[0,\varepsilon)\to[0,\varepsilon)$ that collapses $[0,\varepsilon/2)$ to $0$ and linearly maps $[\varepsilon/2,\varepsilon)$ to the whole interval. Then you use $\varepsilon/2$ as the "new" value for $\varepsilon$. (And oops, I got that arrow backwards in my answer.)